# What's the name for the guitar technique where you use the edge of your pick on wound strings?

Tags: technique, acoustic-guitar

I frequently scrape the edge of my pick along the wound E string and sometimes the A to get a lot of shimmering harmonics. What's the name for this technique?

Comment: Isn't that just called a [Pick scrape / Pick slide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick_slide)?  [Here is an example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z8w1WarL6A4).

Comment: A pickscrape is the succinct term for this.

Comment: @rishimaharaj, if you make this comment an answer, I'll upvote it.

Comment: Too late, I guess!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is known as a pick slide or pick scrape and it is used most often in punk and rock. Read this article for information on what is is. The second article is the forum on proper execution

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick_slide
- http://www.ultimate-guitar.com/forum/archive/index.php?t-616306.html